# Curl SSL Certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: debian, ssl, ssl-certificate

when using `curl` in verbose mode, I get this error:
Command:

```
$ curl -vvI https://www.google.com
```

Error:

> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: none
>   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
> - TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> - TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
> - TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
> - TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
> - TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
> - SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
> - Closing connection 0

But if I send the same command with `sudo`, the connection is setup successfully, so I guess it's a permission issue.

This is what I get with `namei` command:

```
$ namei -mo /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

f: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root etc
drwxr-xr-x root root ssl
drw-r--r-- root root certs
                     ca-certificates.crt - Permission denied
```

So I issued this command:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

That was executed without errors, but the output of `namei` command is the same.

Same thing with /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt

Finally, if I send this command:

```
$ sudo ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I get:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 218664 lug 19 18:51 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access files in the `/etc/ssl/certs` directory because it is missing search permission (`x`). You may fix that with `chmod`, e.g.: `chmod a+x /etc/ssl/certs`

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, you can't access ca-certificates.crt. The curl command tries to access the certificate bundle with your user, but fails. You can fix this by using `chmod`. 755 may be used in this case, as certificate bundles are not sensitive files.

Comment: Sorry to not have mentioned this before... I edit my question